# How to get all the unique combinations of array including blanks (order of items not relevant)

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I have this array:

```
$array = array( 57, 53, 52 );
```

I want to get all the unique combinations of those numbers (order of the items not relevant).

I want a result along the lines of:

```
// 57
// 57, 53
// 57, 53, 52

// 53

// 52
// 52, 57
```

I am using this function, but this returns every combination of the values and as I don't care for the order they are all the same result just in a different order:

```
function my_function( $array ) {

    $combinations = array();
    $words = sizeof( $array );
    $combos = 1;

    for( $i = $words; $i > 0; $i-- ) {

        $combos *= $i;

    }

    while( sizeof( $combinations ) < $combos ) {

        shuffle($array);
        $combo = implode( " ", $array );

        if( !in_array( $combo, $combinations ) ) {

            $combinations[] = $combo;

        }

    }

    return $combinations;

}

print_r( my_function( $array ) );
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `order of the items not relevant` => So I am assuming `53, 57` and `57, 53` are the same.

Comment: yes for my scenario those are the same thing

Comment: @Steveo You should probably update your example than!

Comment: 2^n combinations is quite a few...

Comment: Such a lovely example for a recursive function <3 Wait a minute, solution incomming.

Comment: @Dann just updated it

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function my_function($array){
    $combs = [[]]; // adding empty set for better code clarity
    sort($array); // sort the array to avoid verbose code to handle duplicate combinations
    $set = [];

    foreach($array as $index => $element){
        $temp = [];
        foreach($combs as $curr_comb){
            $new_comb = $curr_comb;
            $new_comb[] = $element;
            $hashed_comb = implode(",",$new_comb);
            if(!isset($set[$hashed_comb])){
                $temp[] = $new_comb;
                $set[$hashed_comb] = true;
            }
        }

        $combs = array_merge($combs,$temp);
    }

    return array_slice($combs,1); // removing the empty set initially added
}

print_r(my_function([57,53,52]));
print_r(my_function([3,3,3]));
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/f3IHs

- We add an empty combination `[]`before to make the code look simple.
- We generate combinations by adding current element to previous generated set of combinations. Like, first it's `[]` which later becomes `[],[57]` which in turn later(in next iteration of first foreach loop) becomes `[],[57],[53],[57,53]` and so on.
- We do an `implode()` and insert in the `set` to remember the combination to avoid duplicacy.

Answer (score 1):

Since order doesn't matter, it seems like we could work our way through in order. Start with the first number and find all combinations, then move on to the second as our starting number, and so on. And since I love recursive functions (function recursion is its own reward), this is how I'd go about it:

```
function unique_combinations( $array, $prefix = '' ) {
    $combinations = array();
    $count = count($array);
    // I use a for loop just to count the number of times to run. Since I'm using array_shift, the array will keep getting smaller
    for( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
        $number = array_shift($array);

        // Grab our current result (this number and any prefixes
        $this_result = trim( "$prefix $number" );
        $combinations[] = $this_result;

        // Now, if the array still has numbers in it, run the function on those numbers and combine results
        if ( count($array) > 0 ) {
            $combinations = array_merge($combinations, unique_combinations( $array, $this_result ) );
        }
    }

    return $combinations;
}

print_r( unique_combinations( [57,58,59] ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar and also pretty short recursive approach with a single anonymous function, `sort` and an early `array_unique`. Should give you what you want, for simplicity the values are sorted in ascending order:

```
// all the logic
$getAllCombinations = function($array) {
    $result = [];
    sort($array);
    $getOrderedCombinations = function ($combination_base, &$result) use (&$getOrderedCombinations) {
        array_push($result,$combination_base);
        if(count($combination_base) > 1) {
            foreach($combination_base as $key => $val) {
                $newcombo = $combination_base;
                unset($newcombo[$key]);
                $getOrderedCombinations($newcombo,$result);
            }
        }
    };
    $getOrderedCombinations($array,$result);
    return array_unique($result,SORT_REGULAR);
};


// execution
$array = array( 57, 53, 52  );
var_dump($getAllCombinations($array));
```